# Error: Cannot find module 'winston-daily-rotate-file' after it worked a few days ago

Tags: node.js, docker, winston

I added winston-daily-rotate-file to some node containers in a docker project I'm working on. They worked approximately a week ago (late January) but today I saw issues where none of the containers I was using it in could find the module for daily-rotate-file. Could something have happened to the source or have I somehow declared it wrong?

```
"winston": "^3.2.1",
"winston-mail": "^2.0.0",
"winston-daily-rotate-file": "4.4.2",
```

from my package.json

```
var winston = require("winston");
var Mail = require("winston-mail").Mail;
var {format} = require("logform");
require("winston-daily-rotate-file");
```

from my log.js file

Comment: Speculation: if you mount a Docker volume for your `node_modules` directory, that actively prevents Docker from ever seeing changes in your `package.json` file.  Do you have declarations like that in a `docker-compose.yml` file (and if so, can you include it in the question)?

Comment: Yeah here, this should be the same from what I worked on last week:
    `volumes:

      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock      

      - ${DATA_FOLDER}/platform/logs:/usr/src/logs

      - ${DEPLOY_PATH}/platform/node:/usr/src/app

      - /usr/src/app/node_modules`

Comment: Yup, that’s telling Docker “ignore all of the code and libraries that are in my image; use the content from the host system instead; never update anything”.  You should delete the volumes for `/usr/src/app` and `/usr/src/app/node_modules` to use the code in the image.